# Confidence interval for a regression parameter via prediction

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, regression-coefficients, poisson-regression

Consider a simple Poisson-regression - GLM - model. There $\exp\left(\beta\right)$s are used as Incidence Rate Ratios (IRR), but their calculation is sometimes not completely straightforward, for instance, if we have interactions (when one has to take the product of such terms). It is especially true if we need a confidence interval for an IRR: it is easy to obtain a CI for a $\beta$, but in that case we need a CI for the *exponentiated* of the *sum* of such parameters.

Motivated by this, I had an idea that might be completely wrong, but I thought it worth asking.

What if I calculate IRRs and their confidence intervals by using predictions? Let me show an example (in R). Take the well-known dataset `warpbreaks`:

```
 head( warpbreaks )
 mod <- glm( breaks ~ wool * tension, warpbreaks, family = poisson )
```

To obtain IRRs:

```
 exp( coefficients( mod ) )
   (Intercept)          woolB       tensionM       tensionH woolB:tensionM woolB:tensionH 
    44.5555556      0.6334165      0.5386534      0.5511222      1.8930264      1.2072719
```

It can be seen what I meant by ''not straightforward'': to obtain IRRs for each covariate combination we need

```
irrmod <- c( 1, exp( coef( mod ) )[ 2:3 ],
exp( coef( mod )[ 2 ] + coef( mod )[ 3 ] + coef( mod )[ 5 ] ), exp( coef( mod )[ 4 ] ),
             exp( coef( mod )[ 2 ] + coef( mod )[ 4 ] + coef( mod )[ 6 ] ) )
cbind( irrmod )
            irrmod
         1.0000000
woolB    0.6334165
tensionM 0.5386534
woolB    0.6458853
tensionH 0.5511222
woolB    0.4214464
```

And we haven't even talked about CIs for these...

So, here is the idea: first, we obtain predictions for each possible combination of explanatory variables.

```
preddata <- expand.grid( wool = levels( warpbreaks$wool ),
    tension = levels( warpbreaks$tension ) )
preds <- predict( mod, newdata = preddata, type = "response", se.fit = TRUE )
irrpred <- preds$fit
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
44.55556 28.22222 24.00000 28.77778 24.55556 18.77778
```

The problem is that these are measured on the response scale, and the (possible?) solution: divide all of them with the first! As these are all categorical variables *I think* this results in IRRs. Indeed, in the concrete example:

```
expbeta0 <- irrpred[ 1 ]
irrpred <- irrpred / expbeta0
cbind( preddata, irrpred, irrmod )
  wool tension   irrpred    irrmod
1    A       L 1.0000000 1.0000000
2    B       L 0.6334165 0.6334165
3    A       M 0.5386534 0.5386534
4    B       M 0.6458853 0.6458853
5    A       H 0.5511222 0.5511222
6    B       H 0.4214464 0.4214464
```

so these are in fact equal. My **first question**: is this method theoretically sound, i.e. is it mathematically guaranteed that the two approaches are equivalent in every situation? I'm quite sure they are, just to be safe.

But now comes the part in which I'm absolutely not sure: what about CIs? Taking this approach further, it is logical to calculate the following:

```
upr <- preds$fit + ( qnorm( 0.975 ) * preds$se.fit )
lwr <- preds$fit - ( qnorm( 0.975 ) * preds$se.fit )
upr <- upr / expbeta0
lwr <- lwr / expbeta0
```

I have to admit that I'm not too familiar with how `predict.glm` calculates standard errors, so I might be completely wrong, but can this method be used to obtain CIs for the IRRs...?

An obvious problem is that this way we get a ''true CI'' even for the reference category (which, of course, should not have a CI, being fixed at $1$). The other problem is that the results are not equal to that of `confint` even in the categories where they are comparable:

```
cbind( preddata, lwr, exp( confint( mod ) )[ , 1 ], upr, exp( confint( mod )[ , 2 ] ) )
Waiting for profiling to be done...
Waiting for profiling to be done...
  wool tension       lwr exp(confint(mod))[, 1]       upr exp(confint(mod)[, 2])
1    A       L 0.9021242             40.3356421 1.0978758             49.0597741
2    B       L 0.5555195              0.5407439 0.7113134              0.7405983
3    A       M 0.4668193              0.4558586 0.6104874              0.6347433
4    B       M 0.5672254              0.4670131 0.7245452              0.6486862
5    A       H 0.4784616              1.4908755 0.6237828              2.4069226
6    B       H 0.3579064              0.9356292 0.4849864              1.5571553
```

Note that only the second and third line is interesting now, as only they pertain to the same combination. (And the fifth row from `upr/low` vs. the fourth row of `confint`.) While they are *quite close*, they do not match exactly...

So my **second question** is: what about the CIs for the IRRs? Can this method, with `predict`, be used to calculate them?